# Sigillare and sugillare

Tags: etymology, meaning, language-evolution

From [*signum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/signum#Latin) ("sign") we have a diminutive form [*sigillum*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sigillum#Latin), "little sign", whence in particular: "wax seal made by one's ring print", to close and sign a letter or a box, which is of course a very common practice in classic Rome and somehow even today. Indeed the English word [seal](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seal#Etymology_2) comes from it --but not *seal* as marine mammal, of course. (Btw, in classic Rome *sigillum* is also a little wax statue, to be used for that purpose). And there is a verb [*sigillare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seal#Etymology_2) for the corresponding action; later, with the extended meaning of  just "to close off", which is e.g. also the current Italian meaning). Late and vulgar Latin  has also an alternative form *sugellare* or *suggellare* with the same meaning (and *suggellare* is also an antiquate Italian form for *sigillare*, in use since the XIX-th century). So far, so good.

Classic Latin has also a well attested verb [*sugillare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=sugillo), from [*sugo, sugere*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/seal#Etymology_2) (to suck), meaning "to mark with bruises" (Plin, Sen, Varr), e.g. *oculus sugillatus ex ictu*, "shiner", and as a derivate meaning, to insult. Therefore *sugillare* and *sigillare* are two classic Latin terms, close in spelling and in meaning, but with different etymology. Besides, how is "to mark with bruises" logically connected to "to suck"?

My conjectural explanation: isn't the original meaning of the verb *sugillare*  "to make a [***love bite***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hickey)"? In this case, it may even be from a substantive **sugillum*, coined as a pun on *sigillum*, and then ironically used from the signs of a punch (like when we say "caress" for "slap").  But, I can find no trace of this funny explanation.

**Edit** I learned that the Spanish term for *love bite/hickey* is [sugilación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugilaci%C3%B3n). This seems to confirm the conjecture, but then, if the original meaninig is really “hickey”, why there is no trace of it?

Comment: I don't know what a love bite is, but I knew very young (50+ years ago) that sucking on my hand or arm very hard for a long time would leave a bruise, so the etymology makes sense to me.

Comment: I’ve added a link to the Wikipedia article on “love bite” (EN) or “hickey” (US)

Comment: There must be a word for love bite in classical Latin, e.g. in Martial or other erotic poets. But what is it?

Comment: @fdb e.g. Propertius 3.8.21-22"in morso aequales videant **mea vulnera collo**: me doceat livor mecum habuisse meam." and 4.5.39-40 "semper habe morsus circa tua colla recentis, dentibus alterius quos putet esse datos"

Comment: also Tibullus 1.16.13-14 "tunc sucos herbasque dedi quis livor abiret quem facit impresso mutua dente venus." There are even more examples mentioned in Hutchinson 2006

Comment: @AlexB. ...sucos .... Is this a pun?

Comment: @fdb it could be, but I'm not so sure